# Debian USB wifi adapter driver issues

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers

I bought this wifi adapter to use with my home server running debian Wheezy,

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00BTWNBH2?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=od_aui_detailpages00](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BTWNBH2)

I installed realtek-firmware and wireless-tools(including NetworkManager and wpasupplicant). I rebooting and plugged in the wireless adapter and it didn't load the driver. After further research, I found that this adapter required the RTL8188EU driver, which I had to install manually.

After manually installing that driver using the source from the iwfinger github(https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu) and rebooting, I plugged in the wireless adapter and it worked. The wireless adapter seemed to work but after testing it under load(downloading a several GB file from the server and uploading a several GB file to the server) I ran into issues during the tests.

I'm not sure what is going on but it seems the driver is failing or it is disconnecting from the network. I checked dmesg and this is what I found,

```
[ 5478.544704] RTL871X: reg 0x80, usb read 4 fail, status:-71 value=0x0, vendorreq_times:1
[ 5478.544707] RTL871X: reg 0x80, usb read 4 fail, status:-19 value=0x0, vendorreq_times:2
[ 5478.544710] RTL871X: reg 0x80, usb read 4 fail, status:-19 value=0x0, vendorreq_times:3
[ 5478.544712] RTL871X: reg 0x80, usb read 4 fail, status:-19 value=0x0, vendorreq_times:4
[ 5478.544714] RTL871X: reg 0x80, usb read 4 fail, status:-19 value=0x0, vendorreq_times:5
[ 5478.544716] RTL871X: [dvobj:ffff8800cab7e400][ERROR] continual_urb_error:5 > 4
[ 5478.572341] RTL871X: _FWFreeToGo8192E: Polling FW ready fail!! REG_MCUFWDL:0x00000000
[ 5478.572342] RTL871X: DL Firmware failed!
[ 5478.572344] RTL871X: rtl8192eu_hal_init: Download Firmware failed!!
[ 5478.572345] RTL871X: rtw_hal_init: hal__init fail
[ 5478.572347] RTL871X: -871x_drv - drv_open fail, bup=0
[ 5478.604058] RTL871X: <=== rtw_dev_unload
[ 5478.604067] RTL871X: +r871xu_dev_remove, hw_init_completed=0
[ 5478.604230] RTL871X: 4free_recv_skb_queue not empty, 8
[ 5478.604241] RTL871X: -r871xu_dev_remove, done
```

I'm somewhat new to Debian and I'm not sure what else to do here. I've search the forums and google, trying multiple solutions with no luck. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.